# Returning permanents from my graveyard

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If i have a sorcery or instant or creature ability that allows me to return target permanent to its owners hand, can I use that ability or spell to return permanents from my graveyard

Answer (score 7):

No, you cannot do that.

Only objects on the battlefield are called [permanents](http://wiki.mtgsalvation.com/article/Permanent). In the graveyard, they are just cards. You can only return cards from the graveyard to the battlefield or to your hand if the spell or ability specifically says "from the graveyard".

Comment: +1 however, I would recommend against using mtgsalvation as a source to link to. They are a nice resource, but I find that their rules sections are often stale when compared to the actual comprehensive rules. You might consider starting with mtgsalvation and then trying to find the same rules quotes in the comprehensive rules text.

Comment: I've never noticed that problem with mtgsalvation. Can you give an example of a stale rules article?

Comment: I forget the big one that made me not want to use it as a citation but here is one minor example: http://wiki.mtgsalvation.com/article/Starting_the_game they are clearly citing the innistrad rules (and they say as such). However in 2014 rule 103.4 changed (slightly) http://www.yawgatog.com/resources/rules-changes/dgm-m14/

Comment: I just wanted to demonstrate that avoiding that wiki is not the only solution. The mtgsalvation link you provided now has the most up-to-date rules.