# Do I "control" creatures in my graveyard?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Cloudshift](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=240006) has

> Exile target creature you control, then return that card to the battlefield under your control.

Are creatures already in my graveyard still under my control? Can I return one of them to the battlefield?

*(No, I don't think [that one](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/14609/returning-permanents-from-my-graveyard) answers my question. It's not "permanent", but "creature you control")*

Comment: In the future, you should probably wait a little while before accepting an answer, so that you can evaluate it against other answers.

Comment: For the reason people can easily see this as a duplicate, see murgatroid's and diego's answers, which clarify that "creature" means "creature permanent." Unfortunately there are probably a half dozen possible duplicates for that half of your question as well...

Comment: Indeed, one distinction that trips people up is that there are never creatures in your graveyard. Only creature *cards*. The only place you find creatures is on the battlefield.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Rule 109.2](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Object) says

> If a spell or ability uses a description of an object that includes a card type or subtype, but doesn't include the word "card," "spell," "source," or "scheme," it means a permanent of that card type or subtype **on the battlefield**.

In its targetting clause, Cloudshift says "creature" without any of the specified words, so it's referring to a creature permanent on the battlefield.

In general, you don't control anything in the graveyard. Rule 109.4 says

> Only objects on the stack or on the battlefield have a controller. Objects that are neither on the stack nor on the battlefield aren't controlled by any player.

Effects that deal with cards in the graveyard would refer to their owner.

Comment: Giving this one my +1, due to being the first correct answer, given that two are essentially the same now, and the other is just plain misleading.

Answer (score 3):

No. You only control creatures on the battlefield and creature spells on the stack. Anywhere else they are creature cards that you own, but do not control.

> **109.4.** Only objects on the stack or on the battlefield have a controller. Objects that are neither on the stack nor on the battlefield aren't controlled by any player.

Though if you control the cards in your graveyard isn't really material, [Otherworldly Journey](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Otherworldly%20Journey) still couldn't target a creature in a graveyard, this is because if a spell or ability doesn't have any sort of qualifier on it (like Creature spell, Land card) it means a permanent on the battlefield.

> **109.2** If a spell or ability uses a description of an object that includes a card type or subtype, but doesn't include the word "card," "spell," "source," or "scheme," it means a permanent of that card type or subtype on the battlefield.

Comment: This isn't really the right reasoning. It's true that you can only control stuff on the battlefield, but the "you control" clause on Cloudshift isn't the **reason** that you can only target stuff on the battlefield.

Comment: @murgatroid99 You're right, while this does answer the question in the title, it isn't exactly answering the one in the body of the question.

Comment: Butt... you say you still own the creatures in your graveyard.. so Trostani Discordant returns cards from the graveyard?

Comment: @JohanSellberg No, because rule 109.2 applies to Trostani Discordant's ability as well.